# can I declare variable in a query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM someTable INNER JOIN someTable ON someTable.tID = someTable.threadID LEFT JOIN someTable ON someTable.ID = someTable.IMAGEID WHERE tID = $_GET["$somevariable"] ';
```

Query above works if I put `tID` manually as numbers. What I want to do is to use `$_GET` method on this page. So `$_GET` method can ask for different numbers when directed to here from other pages

is this possible? if so how to do it?

I'm a beginner so Please don't just give the correct code, but explain why this happens too so I can learn from this.

Comment: FYI Never put $_GET directly into a query

Comment: yes you can. But make a new variable before putting it in the query.

Comment: anything between `'`, will make it string, php will evaluate variables only in `"`

Comment: @Robert how to put it indirectly?

Comment: Filter it in some way to a new variable. $_GET variables can be easily manipulated by the frontend users to add an injection to your sql. The way you filter it is specific to the type of value it is. You can also use PDO which, for the most part, takes care of that.

Comment: thank you, I'll search for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the query works when you manually replace `$_GET` with a number, I would first make sure `$_GET['whatever']` is properly being set. Use `echo var_dump($_GET)` to see all information about that variable. If the variable appears to be properly set, it may also be an issue with concatenation.

Try changing

```
$sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM someTable INNER JOIN someTable ON someTable.tID = someTable.threadID LEFT JOIN someTable ON someTable.ID = someTable.IMAGEID WHERE tID = $_GET["$somevariable"] ';
```

to

```
$sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM someTable INNER JOIN someTable ON someTable.tID = someTable.threadID LEFT JOIN someTable ON someTable.ID = someTable.IMAGEID WHERE tID = '.$_GET["$somevariable"].' ';
```

This will properly insert the variable in to the query.

---

***Important Note***

You don't provide any other code so I don't know if you're properly sanitizing input, but you really shouldn't be writing SQL queries like that anyways. Look to PDO for parameratized statements. If your just injecting `$_GET` into the query, imagine if someone were to type SQL into your form.

Comment: I have `$p = "p";` before query then I put `tID = '.$_GET["$p"].'`

and it gives me undefined index notice

Comment: Where did `$p` come from?

Comment: I have `$p = $_GET["p"];` before query then I put `tID = '."$p".'`

and it gives me undefined variable notice now

Comment: $p is supposed to be the value

Comment: You're probably getting the undefined index notice because you're not properly setting your variables. Use `var_dump()` on every relevant variable to make sure they're being properly set.

Comment: also this is only for a search query. it'll show results. aren't search engines use queries like that to show results? I made links from another search for threads so when people click the topics this search will show the results related to their id's

Comment: Sure, search engines create queries with information from `$_GET`. But they also use parameterized statements to prevent SQL injection. Example: 
`$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=? AND name=?");
$stmt->execute(array($id, $name));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` See [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) tutorial for the benefits of PDO.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll definitely try to implement some of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way:

```
$Id=$_GET["$somevariable"];
$sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM someTable INNER JOIN someTable ON someTable.tID = someTable.threadID LEFT JOIN someTable ON someTable.ID = someTable.IMAGEID WHERE tID = '. $Id ;
```